# What was Guinan really?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

What was the true extent of Guinan's abilities? I noticed in several episodes that alterations to the time stream didn't affect her, i.e. her memory was unaffected. Even more strange, Q seemed to be unsettled by her...the first time he seemed startled, even afraid. And then there's the fact that apparently her species is so long-lived that in 500 years she didn't appear to have aged a day. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/13495 and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/107047

Comment: Guinan almost dies from dehydration in "Time's Arrow." And people think she can take on a Q? Absurd.